# Rails API: send request with nested resources through postman

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postman, nested-forms

I've created a rails api only application. The association between the models are as follows:

```
class Book < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :authors
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :authors, allow_destroy: true
end 

class Author < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :books
end
```

Now, when I'm trying to create a new `Book` with parameters posted from postman,

```
{
    "book": {
        "name": "Angels and Demons",
        "isbn": "12323012123213",
        "authors_attributes": [{"id": 1}, {"id": 2}]
    }
}
```

it gives me the following error: though Author with id 1 exists in DB.

> "message": "Couldn't find Author with ID=1 for Book with ID="

If I changed my form parameters like the following:

```
{
    "book": {
        "name": "Angels and Demons",
        "isbn": "12323012123213",
        "authors_attributes": [{"0": {"id": 1}}, {"1": {"id": 2}}]
    }
}
```

It gives me validation error from the `Author` model.

Controller strong parameters:

```
def book_params
    params.require(:book).permit(:name, :isbn, authors_attributes: [:id, :_destroy])
  end
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @Mezbah, Yes, I did mentioned that on the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to associate a book with existing authors you don't need nested attributes- just pass an array of ids as `book_ids`:

```
{
    "book": {
        "name": "Angels and Demons",
        "isbn": "12323012123213",
        "author_ids": [1,2]
    }
}
```

ActiveRecord will create `*association_name*_ids` getters and setters for all `has_many` and HABTM associations.

Use nested attributes only if the associated record needs to be created/updated on the fly in the same request. For an API app, I would avoid nested attributes since you end up bending the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

Comment: So, in that case I don't need the `accepts_nested_attributes_for`?

Comment: No not if you just want to associate a record with other existing records.

Comment: For an API app you'll never really want to use `accepts_nested_attributes_for`. Its kind of a kludge for classical web apps for when you want to stuff a bunch of functionality into a single form / request without resorting to ajax.